Get the Error with siunitx
Now I recompile the answer at here
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
            }}
        \num{48,5} & 43 & 50 & 55 & 45 & 60 & 53 & \num{55,5} & 44 & 65 \\
        51 & 62,5 & 41 & \num{44,5} & 57 & 57 & 68 & 49 & 46,5 & \num{53,5} \\
        61 & \num{49,5} & 54 & 62 & 59 & 56 & 47 & 50 & 60 & 61 \\
        \num{49,5} & \num{52,5} & 57 & 47 & 60 & 55 & 45 & \num{47,5} & 48 & \num{61,5}
        \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}

I got the massage

How can I prepair it?
log.file
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.6.13)  16 JUN 2024 15:40
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./test_decimal.tex
(test_decimal.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-05-08>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count194
\c@section=\count195
\c@subsection=\count196
\c@subsubsection=\count197
\c@paragraph=\count198
\c@subparagraph=\count199
\c@figure=\count266
\c@table=\count267
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen141
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tabularray\tabularray.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-05-08 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count268
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
))
Package: tabularray 2024-02-16 v2024A Typeset tabulars and arrays with LaTeX3
\l__tblr_a_int=\count269
\l__tblr_c_int=\count270
\l__tblr_r_int=\count271
\l__tblr_d_dim=\dimen142
\l__tblr_h_dim=\dimen143
\l__tblr_o_dim=\dimen144
\l__tblr_p_dim=\dimen145
\l__tblr_q_dim=\dimen146
\l__tblr_r_dim=\dimen147
\l__tblr_s_dim=\dimen148
\l__tblr_t_dim=\dimen149
\l__tblr_v_dim=\dimen150
\l__tblr_w_dim=\dimen151
\l__tblr_a_box=\box53
\l__tblr_b_box=\box54
\l__tblr_c_box=\box55
\l__tblr_d_box=\box56
\g__tblr_table_count_int=\count272
\c@rownum=\count273
\c@colnum=\count274
\c@rowcount=\count275
\c@colcount=\count276
\abovesep=\dimen152
\belowsep=\dimen153
\leftsep=\dimen154
\rightsep=\dimen155
\g_tblr_level_int=\count277
\g__tblr_data_row_key_count_int=\count278
\g__tblr_data_column_key_count_int=\count279
\g__tblr_data_cell_key_count_int=\count280
\g__tblr_array_int=\count281
\l__tblr_key_count_int=\count282
\l__tblr_key_quotient_int=\count283
\l__tblr_key_quotient_two_int=\count284
\l__tblr_key_remainder_int=\count285
\g__tblr_data_str_value_count_int=\count286
\rulewidth=\dimen156
\l__tblr_strut_dp_dim=\dimen157
\l__tblr_strut_ht_dim=\dimen158
\g__tblr_cell_wd_dim=\dimen159
\g__tblr_cell_ht_dim=\dimen160
\g__tblr_cell_head_dim=\dimen161
\g__tblr_cell_foot_dim=\dimen162
\l__column_target_dim=\dimen163
\l__tblr_caption_box=\box57
\l__tblr_caption_left_box=\box58
\l__tblr_row_head_box=\box59
\l__tblr_row_foot_box=\box60
\l__tblr_row_head_foot_dim=\dimen164
\tablewidth=\dimen165
\l__tblr_table_firsthead_box=\box61
\l__tblr_table_middlehead_box=\box62
\l__tblr_table_lasthead_box=\box63
\l__tblr_table_firstfoot_box=\box64
\l__tblr_table_middlefoot_box=\box65
\l__tblr_table_lastfoot_box=\box66
\l__tblr_remain_height_dim=\dimen166
\l__tblr_long_from_int=\count287
\l__tblr_long_to_int=\count288
\l__tblr_curr_i_int=\count289
\l__tblr_prev_i_int=\count290
\l__tblr_table_page_int=\count291
\l__tblr_table_head_box=\box67
\l__tblr_table_foot_box=\box68
\l__tblr_table_head_foot_dim=\dimen167
\l__tblr_table_head_body_foot_dim=\dimen168
\l__tblr_table_box=\box69
\l__tblr_table_hlines_box=\box70
\l__tblr_hline_box=\box71
\l__tblr_row_box=\box72
\l__tblr_col_o_wd_dim=\dimen169
\l__tblr_col_b_wd_dim=\dimen170
\l__tblr_hline_leftskip_dim=\dimen171
\l__tblr_hline_rightskip_dim=\dimen172
\l__tblr_row_ht_dim=\dimen173
\l__tblr_row_dp_dim=\dimen174
\l__tblr_row_abovesep_dim=\dimen175
\l__tblr_row_belowsep_dim=\dimen176
\l__tblr_row_vlines_box=\box73
\l__tblr_vline_box=\box74
\l__tblr_cell_box=\box75
\l__row_upper_dim=\dimen177
\l__row_lower_dim=\dimen178
\l__row_vpace_dim=\dimen179
\l__tblr_vline_aboveskip_dim=\dimen180
\l__tblr_vline_belowskip_dim=\dimen181
\l__tblr_cell_wd_dim=\dimen182
\l__tblr_cell_ht_dim=\dimen183
\l__tblr_diag_box=\box76
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/diagbox\diagbox.sty
Package: diagbox 2020/02/09 v2.3 Making table heads with diagonal lines

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pict2e\pict2e.sty
Package: pict2e 2020/09/30 v0.4b Improved picture commands (HjG,RN,JT)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pict2e\pict2e.cfg
File: pict2e.cfg 2016/02/05 v0.1u pict2e configuration for teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package pict2e Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 112.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2024/04/13 v1.2c Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package pict2e Info: Driver file for pict2e: p2e-pdftex.def on input line 114.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pict2e\p2e-pdftex.def
File: p2e-pdftex.def 2016/02/05 v0.1u Driver-dependant file (RN,HjG,JT)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
\pIIe@GRAPH=\toks18
\@arclen=\dimen184
\@arcrad=\dimen185
\pIIe@tempdima=\dimen186
\pIIe@tempdimb=\dimen187
\pIIe@tempdimc=\dimen188
\pIIe@tempdimd=\dimen189
\pIIe@tempdime=\dimen190
\pIIe@tempdimf=\dimen191
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty
Package: calc 2023/07/08 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count292
\calc@Bcount=\count293
\calc@Adimen=\dimen192
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen193
\calc@Askip=\skip51
\calc@Bskip=\skip52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count294
\calc@Cskip=\skip53
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\array.sty
Package: array 2023/10/16 v2.5g Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen194
\ar@mcellbox=\box77
\extrarowheight=\dimen195
\NC@list=\toks19
\extratabsurround=\skip54
\backup@length=\skip55
\ar@cellbox=\box78
)
\diagbox@boxa=\box79
\diagbox@boxb=\box80
\diagbox@boxm=\box81
\diagbox@wd=\dimen196
\diagbox@ht=\dimen197
\diagbox@insepl=\dimen198
\diagbox@insepr=\dimen199
\diagbox@outsepl=\dimen256
\diagbox@outsepr=\dimen257
) (siunitx.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2024-05-08 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: siunitx 2021-04-17 v2.8e A comprehensive (SI) units package

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen258
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2024-05-08 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
\l__siunitx_tmp_box=\box82
\l__siunitx_tmp_dim=\dimen259
\l__siunitx_tmp_int=\count295
\l__siunitx_number_mantissa_length_int=\count296
\l__siunitx_number_uncert_length_int=\count297
\l__siunitx_round_int=\count298
\l__siunitx_process_decimal_int=\count299
\l__siunitx_process_uncertainty_int=\count300
\l__siunitx_process_fixed_int=\count301
\l__siunitx_process_integer_min_int=\count302
\l__siunitx_process_precision_int=\count303
\l__siunitx_group_min_int=\count304
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_box=\box83
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_box=\box84
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_dim=\dimen260
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_dim=\dimen261
\l__siunitx_unit_int=\count305
\l__siunitx_unit_denominator_int=\count306
\l__siunitx_unit_numerator_int=\count307
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_int=\count308
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_base_int=\count309
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_gram_int=\count310
\l__siunitx_number_product_int=\count311
\c__siunitx_one_fill_skip=\skip56
\l__siunitx_table_unit_align_skip=\skip57
\l__siunitx_table_exponent_dim=\dimen262
\l__siunitx_table_integer_dim=\dimen263
\l__siunitx_table_mantissa_dim=\dimen264
\l__siunitx_table_marker_dim=\dimen265
\l__siunitx_table_result_dim=\dimen266
\l__siunitx_table_uncert_dim=\dimen267
\l__siunitx_table_fill_pre_dim=\dimen268
\l__siunitx_table_fill_post_dim=\dimen269
\l__siunitx_table_fill_mid_dim=\dimen270
\l__siunitx_table_pre_box=\box85
\l__siunitx_table_post_box=\box86
\l__siunitx_table_mantissa_box=\box87
\l__siunitx_table_result_box=\box88
\l__siunitx_table_number_align_skip=\skip58
\l__siunitx_table_text_align_skip=\skip59

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/translator\translator.sty
Package: translator 2021-05-31 v1.12d Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
))
No file test_decimal.aux.
\openout1 = `test_decimal.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count312
\scratchdimen=\dimen271
\scratchbox=\box89
\nofMPsegments=\count313
\nofMParguments=\count314
\everyMPshowfont=\toks21
\MPscratchCnt=\count315
\MPscratchDim=\dimen272
\MPnumerator=\count316
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count317
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks22
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/siunitx\siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
File: siunitx-abbreviations.cfg 2021-04-17 v2.8e siunitx: Abbreviated units
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/translator\translator-basic-dictionary-Engli
sh.dict
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Language: English 
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 7.
> Step: init table outer spec.
> Step: parse table options.
> Step: split table.
> Step: init table inner spec.
> Step: parse table inner spec.
> Step: execute table commands.
> Step: calculate cell and line sizes.


! Package siunitx Error: Invalid token '\num ' in numerical input.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.28     \end
             {tblr}
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.28     \end
             {tblr}

Numbers can only contain tokens defined using the 'input-...' options:
the token '\num ' is not set up as a valid part of a number.


 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5856 strings out of 473937
 143861 string characters out of 5737188
 1926893 words of memory out of 5000000
 28703 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 561043 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 65i,4n,120p,225b,697s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


compiles fine here. Show your log-file.

Compiles fine on a MacTeX2024 system with all updates applied. (Version of siunitx in use: 3.3.18, dated 2024-06-14.) Just out of idle curiosity: What's the purpose of the \num wrappers? They look utterly redundant to me...

As suggested in David's ansewr, you have v2 of siunitx but a more up-to-date system otherwise: the file siunitx.sty seems to be in the current directory

Why you use num{...} in S columns? I don't see any sense for douing this.

If you modify your example so it has
\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]

which forces a legacy version 2 of siunitx to be loaded,
then you get the error shown:
! Package siunitx Error: Invalid token '\num ' in numerical input.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.28     \end
             {tblr}
?

So either you have a very old latex distribution that still has siunitx version 2 rather than version 3 or (perhaps more likely) you have an old local version of siunitx.sty that is masking the version in your tex distribution.
Your log should look like
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
...
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
Package: siunitx 2024-05-06 v3.3.17 A comprehensive (SI) units package

with siunitx.sty showing v3.x.x and being found in a sibling directory to article.cls

As Zako'comment, you can move \num{...}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
  \begin{tblr}{colspec=*{10}{X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]}}  
 48.5 & 43 & 50 & 55 & 45 & 60 & 53 & 55.5 & 44 & 65 \\
 51 & 62.5 & 41 & 44.5 & 57 & 57 & 68 & 49 & 46.5 & 53.5 \\
 61 & 49.5 & 54 & 62 & 59 & 56 & 47 & 50 & 60 & 61 \\
 49.5 & 52.5 & 57 & 47 & 60 & 55 & 45 & 47.5 & 48 & 61.5
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document} 


